# Is page authority or domain authority more important for backlinks?

Tags: seo, pagerank, backlinks

When you are searching for potential sources of backlinks. Is page authority or domain authority more important for search engines?

Comment: It's different for different search engines.

Comment: Equally I would say, if a domain has high authority it is likely that many pages will and visa-versa

Comment: Relevancy is the most important fact, too many off topic links will hurt. But your first mistake is looking for back links, focus on quality content and link baiting.

Answer (score 1):

I think page authority is more important for search engines in general because they analyze precisely the page from the backlinks come. But of course, page authority depends on domain authority.

However, page or domain authority is a subjective and predefined factors notion. Each search engines or site of backlinks analysis (like [Open Site Explorer from Moz](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/) or [Ahrefs](https://ahrefs.com/)) have a definition of authority.

A factor of authority can be important for one search engine and less important for another. That's why it's hard to say if authority is in general an accurate factor to take into account for SEO. It's more reliable to talk about a specific factor for one specific search engine.